# Pointer pointing to a string pointer array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a pointer array of strings:

```
string *names = new string[numOfNames];
```

That array is then populated with values from a file. I am trying to sort the names alphabetically so I am trying to assign another pointer array to the address of each individual element names is pointing to. So I want to do something like this:

```
string *namesPtr = new string[numOfNames];
namesPtr[0] = &names[0];
```

However I am getting a red squiggly on the equal sign saying

> no operator "=" matches these operands, operand types are std::string = std::string*

I have a pointer array of names because numOfNames will be specified in the file I am going to open and from my understanding, a regular array won't work because I have to specify the number of elements in the array.

Comment: What is a "pointer array"? Do you mean a "pointer to a dynamically allocated array"?

Comment: @immibis Yeah, I realized that and shamefully deleted my comment.

Comment: Yes, I mean a pointer to a dynamically allocated array. Is there a word for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course there is a type mismatch.

Type of `namesPtr[0]` is `string`.
Type of `&names[0]` is `string*`.

What you need is:

```
string** namesPtr = new string*[numOfNames];
namesPtr[0] = &names[0];
```

To make the pointer assignments complete, you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numNames; ++i )
{
   namesPtr[i] = &names[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would upvote you but I don't have enough rep yet :/

Comment: @Jumpman, you can accept an answer to your question regardless of how many reputation points you have. This will indicate to other users that you have an acceptable answer so they don't waste their time in trying to answer the question.

Comment: Will do. Just clicked the green check mark. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
namesPtr[0] = &names[0];
```

This is incorrect. & will produce the address of the dereferenced string in names, thus you are assigning an address to a string which is illegal.